# How to add a space between words?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a string that has words without any spaces between them. How do I add a space between each word? Example: my string has combined words `FinancialTimes` and I would like it to show as `Financial Times`

```
<?php $word = 'FinancialTimes';?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `preg_replace` with a regex option:

```php
$word = "FinancialTimes";
$output = preg_replace("/(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/", " ", $word);
echo $output;  // Financial Times
```